# InvalidOperationException: Connection string "DefaultConnection" was not found

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core, razor, entity-framework-core

I'm newbie for Razor.

Created below entry in appsettings.json

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

Attempting to run below command

```
@{
    var _db = Database.Open("DefaultConnection");
    var selectQueryString = "SELECT * from Book";
}
```

Gives below Error.
InvalidOperationException: Connection string "DefaultConnection" was not found.
 var _db = Database.Open("DefaultConnection");

Below has been included in the index.cshtml Script.

```
@using WebMatrix.Data;
@using System.Data.SqlClient
```

Book Table does exists in the Database.

Please suggest If I'm missing anything.

Here is the complete code

```
@page
@using WebMatrix.Data;
@using System.Data.SqlClient


@model BookListRazor.Pages.Databases.IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Web Pages Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello Web Pages</h1>
    <p>The time is @DateTime.Now</p>
</body>



@{
    var db1 = Database.Open("DefaultConnection");
    var selectQueryString = "SELECT name,Database_id,Compatibility_level,collation_name FROM sys.databases ORDER BY Name";
}



<body>
    <h1>Databases</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>Database_id</th>
            <th>Compatibility_level</th>
            <th>collation_name</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var row in db1.Query(selectQueryString))
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@row.name</td>
                <td>@row.Database_id</td>
                <td>@row.Compatibility_level</td>
                <td>@row.collation_name</td>
            </tr>

        }
    </table>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: In this article [entity-framework-database-first-in-asp-net-core](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/entity-framework-database-first-in-asp-net-core2) tells you where to put connection string (the same, in **appsettings.json** ) and how to get via `IConfiguration.GetConnectionString` . You can test your `Database.Open` method by similar or same behavior like that.

Answer (score 0):

The `Database.Open` is expecting the proper Connection String, and it is not trying to resolve it from the `appsettings.json`. Try the following code to resolve it through `IConfiguration`.

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration

@{
    var db1 = Database.Open(Configuration["DefaultConnection"]);
    var selectQueryString = "SELECT name,Database_id,Compatibility_level,collation_name FROM sys.databases ORDER BY Name";
}
```

Comment: No Luck with injection.
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or an empty string. (Parameter 'name')
WebMatrix.Data.Database.Open(string name)

Comment: Please debug the code and check the actual value of ConnectionString `DefaultConnection`. And please check if `Database.Open("Server=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True")` can work as expected.

Comment: Both seem to return null. 

Database.Open(Configuration["DefaultConnection"]);

Database.Open("Server=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Books;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");